# Some Javascript Not Running Properly in 64 Bit Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, x86, 64-bit

**EDIT**: Juan Mendez's solution fixed this particular problem, but does not explain the more general question of why this worked on 32 bit and not 64 bit for the exact same browser. Just makes me wonder what other issues like this might exist and how to take preventative action against them... Here is the original question:

---

I have IE 9 installed on two Windows 7 machines, one 32 bit and the other 64. All of the IE options / security settings are identical.

On the 32 bit machine, the following website displays correctly. Notice the scrolling social media icons about midway down the page are in motion, scrolling to the left:

http://www.nba.com/warriors/social-media-new-test

On the 64 bit machine, the script doesn't seem to be running as the icons do not move. Other scripts on the page are running fine (for instance the header has some javascript controlling which image to display).

Here is the code which makes the icons move, however I fear this is a larger (less specific) problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(scrollIcons, 40);
});

function scrollIcons() {
    var i, thisPos, newPosLeft;

    for (i=0; i < numIcons; i++) {
        thisPos = $(iconButtons[i]).position();

        newPosLeft = thisPos.left - (1 * scrollspeed);
        if (newPosLeft < SLIDERLEFTBORDER) newPosLeft = SLIDERRIGHTBORDER;

        $(iconButtons[i]).attr("style", "left: " + newPosLeft + "px;");
    }
}
```

Anyone know what the issue could be? Am I wrong about the 64 bit vs. 32 bit assumption? That just seems to be the only difference between the machines to me.

Comment: do you see any error messages?

Comment: no error messages, simply doesn't seem to want to run it

Comment: Please eliminate unsightly eval-ish strings from `setTimeout` calls and just put function reference there instead. You'll probably better off with `setInterval`.

Comment: @DougieBear take Oleg's suggestion and try it again, console some test output if you need to

Comment: `setInterval("scrollIcons()", 40);` ---> `setInterval(scrollIcons, 40);` is what Oleg was suggesting

Comment: Thanks Kevin, @Oleg k made that change, but still no dice on 64 bit :/

Comment: I disagree with using `setInterval`. That can be a source of performance problems if your handler takes longer than your interval (or if some other event handling is taking longer than the interval). By calling your next animation frame on your own, you avoid that problem. The best way to do animations is with `requestAnimationFrame` http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: I wouldn't update the "style" that way: `$(iconButtons[i]).css('left', newPosLeft + 'px');` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Juan thanks for that article I'll read up on that, looks very interesting and the animation very smooth). Also thanks Pointy I made that change

Comment: @DougieBear I didn't get notified when you added (at)Juan to your comment, you need to add the full name, minus spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your page on IE 8 64-bit, I get the following error:

```
// Object doesn't support this property or method
divs = document.getElementsByClassName('icon_socialmedia');
```

Use `jQuery` instead since you're already using in other places

Comment: k i changed that line to divs = $(".icon_socialmedia"); and it works. This is still troublesome to me, however, since it worked fine on 32 bit but not 64 for the exact same browser. I wonder what else is affected by this....

Comment: @DougieBear I wouldn't worry about it much. You were using a newer API, that's not widely supported, that's what `jQuery` and the like are for.